# Heap and Stack when I use an instance variable in a method (Java Memory)

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

```
public class Main {
    private String sampleName= "Sample";
    public void show() {
        System.out.println(sampleName);
    }
}
```

I know "Sample" as a object locates in heap section, but Where is "sampleName" as a reference variable? if it locates in heap, whether in stack I have another reference with name "sampleName" that reference to "sampleName" in heap ?

Comment: The reference variable lives on the heap as part of the `Main` object.

Comment: @shmosel when println method calls, how can we access from stack frame to "sampleName" reference ? I think sampleName as argument acts like local variable and locates on stack. Is it right ?

Comment: Once it's passed as an argument, it gets pushed onto the stack.

Answer (score 0):

> I know "Sample" as a object locates in heap section

Correct.

> but Where is "sampleName" as a reference variable?

In the `Main` object, which by definition is in the heap.

> if it locates in heap, whether in stack I have another reference with name "sampleName" that reference to "sampleName" in heap

Yes, as a temporary for the argument to `println()`.

Answer (score -1):

Your thread would only hold a reference to the enclosing `Main` object. It points to the `Main` object allocated in the heap. The `sampleName` reference is a field of the `Main` object, hence also on the heap, pointing to the String `"Sample"`, which is maintained in the java constant String pool (another section in the heap). There can't be a `sampleName` reference on the stack since it's a private field; otherwise, you would be able to access it in your code outside of the `Main` class, which is violating the java language semantics. If you defined the `sampleName` field to be `public`, and in your code you did

```
Main main = new Main();
String copyOfSampleName = main.sampleName;
```

Then you would have a `String` reference on your stack that is pointing, together with the original `sampleName` reference, to the `String` object in the constant pool.

Comment: when show method calls, a new variable automatically creates and put in stack and then references  to sampleName instance variable. Is it mean ?

Comment: @Hamid that's not what happens. Well the `sampleName` variable is implicitly referenced by the current thread through the `Main` object, right? So when the `show` method is invoked, the 'this' reference of `Main` would be passed to the stack frame of the method invocation, and `System.out.println(sampleName);` would be executed inside the scope of the `Main` object. Since private fields can be accessed inside the class, the value of `sampleName`can be printed out.

Comment: A more detailed explanation would probably require deeper understanding of java method invocation mechanisms. Read https://www.javaworld.com/article/2076949/learn-java/how-the-java-virtual-machine-handles-method-invocation-and-return.html?page=2 or similar materials if interested.